# What's wrong with this ICS file?

Tags: php, icalendar

I have a question, if someone would be so kind.

Well actually it's two, interdependent questions.

I'm making a calendar file, I'm not used to writing files, although it seems straightforward to write this to a .txt file.

1. Do I need to write headers for an .ics file and how do it do this if so?
2. What's wrong with this that won't open in iCal (MacOS)?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND: 19700101T024640Z
UID: 5724dce4946da
DTSTAMP:20160430T162716Z
LOCATION:Green Park Station
DESCRIPTION:The Urban Playground Team are the original performance-parkour (2PK) company combining urban & contemporary dance with authentic French Free-Running. The Team have toured their performances and teaching across five continents for clients including the British Council. Since 2006 the team has included co-creator of Parkour Malik Diouf. In 2009 the Team designed and opened the UKâ€™s first permanent parkour site\, and have since launched two more. In 2013 they founded the international performance-parkour network to support the development of 2PK globally.  They have appeared on BBC1â€™s Blue Peter and Sky1â€™s Got To Dance. <br />
Steam is a touring performance\, in which a group of urban explorers discover\, beneath canvas tarps\, the skeletal remains of a machine that changed the world. Inspired\, they shovel coal on the fires of the past. Engineers and drivers hurry to work at the sounds of a whistleâ€™s blast\, and the passengers begin to dance. Inspired by classic movie genre Steam takes the UPG Team on a whistle stop tour through silent movies\, the Wild West\, James Bond\, WWI and the dark future of inner city commutingâ€¦<br />
Try out your own skills after the show - and you could even become part of the next performance!<br />
See also Weds June 1st.
URL;VALUE=URI:http://bathfringe.co.uk/single-event?u_name=Steam
SUMMARY:Steam
DTSTART:19700101T000000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

the contents are generated like this:

```
$contents = 

'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND: '.dateToCal($dateend) .'
UID: '. uniqid() .'
DTSTAMP:'. dateToCal(time()) .'
LOCATION:'. escapeString($address) .'
DESCRIPTION:'. escapeString($description) .'
URL;VALUE=URI:'. escapeString($uri) .'
SUMMARY:'. escapeString($summary) .'
DTSTART:'.dateToCal($datestart) .'
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR '
```

Comment: Just a note; I thought it might be the date invalid as it's Jan 1 1970 above but I've changed that using `time()` and it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

## Issue 1 - additional white spaces

Your iCal file contains a couple of white spaces at illegal positions:

```
DTEND: 19700101T024640Z
      ^

UID: 5724dce4946da
    ^

END:VCALENDAR 
             ^
```

Well, technically the second one is probably not invalid, since `UID` is defined to have a `TEXT` value, but you should be prepared for getting into trouble with this. Some implementations might fail to read this, others might strip the space, others might include it.

Check out the ABNF in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) for the correct syntax. In general there are no optional white spaces in iCalendar.

## Issue 2 - incorrect escaping

The `DESCRIPTION` property contains serveral new line sequences, but it's not properly escaped. The new line characters at the end of content lines should be escaped as `\n` (see [RFC 5545, Section 3.3.11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.11)). So the DESCRIPTION property should read like this (all in one line with escaped new line characters):

```
DESCRIPTION:The Urban Playground Team are the original performance-parkour (2PK) company combining urban & contemporary dance with authentic French Free-Running. The Team have toured their performances and teaching across five continents for clients including the British Council. Since 2006 the team has included co-creator of Parkour Malik Diouf. In 2009 the Team designed and opened the UKâ€™s first permanent parkour site\, and have since launched two more. In 2013 they founded the international performance-parkour network to support the development of 2PK globally.  They have appeared on BBC1â€™s Blue Peter and Sky1â€™s Got To Dance. <br />\nSteam is a touring performance\, in which a group of urban explorers discover\, beneath canvas tarps\, the skeletal remains of a machine that changed the world. Inspired\, they shovel coal on the fires of the past. Engineers and drivers hurry to work at the sounds of a whistleâ€™s blast\, and the passengers begin to dance. Inspired by classic movie genre Steam takes the UPG Team on a whistle stop tour through silent movies\, the Wild West\, James Bond\, WWI and the dark future of inner city commutingâ€¦<br />\nTry out your own skills after the show - and you could even become part of the next performance!<br />\nSee also Weds June 1st.
```

Better yet, fold the lines like so

```
DESCRIPTION:The Urban Playground Team are the original performance-park 
 our (2PK) company combining urban & contemporary dance with authentic 
 French Free-Running. The Team have toured their performances and teach
 ing across five continents for clients including the British Council. 
 Since 2006 the team has included co-creator of Parkour Malik Diouf. In
  2009 the Team designed and opened the UKâ€™s first permanent parkour 
 site\, and have since launched two more. In 2013 they founded 
 the international performance-parkour network to support the development 
 of 2PK globally.  They have appeared on BBC1â€™s Blue Peter and Sky1â€™s 
 Got To Dance. <br />\nSteam is a touring performance\, in which a group 
 of urban explorers discover\, beneath canvas tarps\, the skeletal 
 remains of a machine that changed the world. Inspired\, they shovel coal 
 on the fires of the past. Engineers and drivers hurry to work at the 
 sounds of a whistleâ€™s blast\, and the passengers begin to dance. 
 Inspired by classic movie genre Steam takes the UPG Team on a whistle 
 stop tour through silent movies\, the Wild West\, James Bond\, WWI and 
 the dark future of inner city commutingâ€¦<br />\nTry out your own 
 skills after the show - and you could even become part of the next 
 performance!<br />\nSee also Weds June 1st.
```

Note the leading white space at the start of each line. Folding is explained in [Section 3.1 of RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1).

Also note that HTML tags are not supported by iCalendar. Clients may or may not interpret this the way you intended. Some clients will just show the `<br />` tags in plan text. Though, no iCalendar validator should complain about this.

Regarding the headers, the correct content type for iCalendar is `text/calendar`, so if you return this over HTTP you send the following header:

```
Content-type: text/calendar
```

If you want to publish this as a calendar that a calendar application can subscribe to you should consider adding a `METHOD:PUBLISH` field to the `VCALENDAR` object as explained in [RFC 5546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.1).

Lastly: Consider to use an existing iCalendar library that can handle all that for you (the escaping, folding ...). Have a look at [Sabre-VObject](https://github.com/fruux/sabre-vobject).

Comment: Thank you! Once again I'm in above my paygrade. I have the white space licked. HTML coder's carelessness I'm afraid. 
Struggling with the DESCRIPTION; That's how it's delivered to me as a variable. I shall now go and read up on escaping it (currently done by a regex but obviously not properly).

Comment: Although I'm not really following the folding in the RFC 5546, I have found that `strip_tags($description`) followed by `json_encode($description)` produces the required result.

Comment: Note that JSON escaping and iCalendar escaping is not the same, so you will get incorrect results for certain characters. In JSON Strings you have to escape `"` since it's a reserved char, but it's not in iCalendar so it should not be escaped. On the other hand, `,` and `;` are special chars in iCalendar and have to be escaped in regular texts, which is not the case in JSON.

Comment: I really recommend to have a look at Sabre-VObject which takes care of all that and makes it really easy to generate valid iCalendar data.

Answer (score 0):

$eol = "\r\n";

```
$contents = 

'BEGIN:VCALENDAR'.$eol.'
VERSION:2.0'.$eol.'
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN'.$eol.'
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN'.$eol.'
BEGIN:VEVENT'.$eol.'
DTEND: '.dateToCal($dateend) .$eol.'
UID: '. uniqid() .$eol.'
DTSTAMP:'. dateToCal(time()) .$eol.'
LOCATION:'. escapeString($address) .$eol.'
DESCRIPTION:'. escapeString($description) .$eol.'
URL;VALUE=URI:'. escapeString($uri) .$eol.'
SUMMARY:'. escapeString($summary) .$eol.'
DTSTART:'.dateToCal($datestart) .$eol.'
END:VEVENT'.$eol.'
END:VCALENDAR '.$eol;
```

the main thing is you need to add $eol after each link break.

Comment: It's still throwing an arror in iCal. "Calendar can’t read this calendar file."